# Two-dimensional array from array separated by unequal sections

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have a UICollectionView with 40 cells etc. While scrolling I request advertisement, and if there is one, I should display it between first 5 cells. Then, when I scroll forward, I should request the second one, and display it between second 5 cells. For example, I scrolled to the 4th cell, requested advertisement, it came, I showed it between 5th and 6th cells, and so on.

I've decided to create section for those ads between cells. Now I need to re-orginize my array of elements.

Before:

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        items.count
}
```

After:

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return splitPublications.count
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return splitPublications[section].count
}
```

My `splitPublications` array is a two-dimensional array which I need to organize based on advertisements array count. So in the end I should get smth like this:

> Section 1 - (0,1,2,3,4)
>
> Section 2 - (5,6,7,8,9)

*IF ONLY 2 ADS

> Section 3 - (10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20...40) and so on

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do what you want.  It uses `prefix` and `dropFirst` to peal off the items until it has made the appropriate number of sections minus 1, and then puts the remaining items in the last section:

```
func makeSections<T>(items: [T], numberPerSection: Int, maxSectionCount: Int) -> [[T]] {
    var items = items
    var result = [[T]]()
    
    while !items.isEmpty && result.count < maxSectionCount - 1 {
        result.append(Array(items.prefix(numberPerSection)))
        items = Array(items.dropFirst(numberPerSection))
    }
    
    if !items.isEmpty {
        result.append(items)
    }
    
    return result
}
```

**Example:**

```
let items = Array(0...40)

// If we have 2 ads, we will have 3 maximum sections
print(makeSections(items: items, numberPerSection: 5, maxSectionCount: 3))
```

**Output:**

> ```
> [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40]]
> ```

Comment: + listen for what cell will be displayed via [`collectionView:willDisplayCell:forItemAtIndexPath:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegate/1618087-collectionview?language=objc) and add your ad sections when your conditions are met.

Comment: Did that answer your question, Emma?